# If the real time inference in sagemaker does not return output in 1 min , how many times does it retries? and how can we stop those retry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I hosted one large model in Sagemaker using real-time inference but it is not giving any error in case of timeout and retrying by itself after 1 min 2 times. Also how much size is considered to be too large for sagemaker models ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey [Sparsh Rawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8065820/sparsh-rawat)

SageMaker *Pipelines* have automatic [retry policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pipelines-retry-policy.html), however, this only occurs with Pipeline-based executions.

If you have a regular SageMaker Real-time Inference Endpoint, then there shouldn't be any retry behaviour. It is common practice, however, to include retry functionality in multi-model containers ([see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-multi-model-build-container.html#multi-model-inference-toolkit)).

As for the size of a model, it depends. To give you an idea of size requirements:

- [`ml.g4dn.xlarge`](https://instances.vantage.sh/aws/ec2/g4dn.xlarge) instances have 16GB of GPU memory, and can host all (non-LLM) transformer models, such as BERT, RoBERTa, DeBERTa, etc.
- An [`ml.p3.8xlarge`](https://instances.vantage.sh/aws/ec2/p3.8xlarge) instance can host smaller-variants of Large Language Models (LLMs). I've personally had success running Llama2-13B on these instances.

If you would like to introduce timeout functionality, SageMaker has a [60s limit when calling InvokeEndpoint](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1119) — this cannot be modified.

You may wish to use [`timeout-function-decorator`](https://github.com/MatteoH2O1999/timeout_decorator) to add timeout behaviour to your inference code.

Good luck!

Comment: Real-time Inference Endpoint was retrying by itself @fucalost as it was not able to give results within 60 seconds. I did not add any retry in my code
couldn't find anything related to retries in docs

Comment: How were you invoking the endpoint?

Comment: like a normal api endpoint call